# "on_server_role_update" TypeError Missing Argument

Tags: typeerror, discord.py

So... I dont know what to say, im going to be quick obviously

**CODE:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_server_role_update(role, before, after):
print("[" + (colored("{}".format(role.server), 'blue')) + "] " + (colored("Role Updated: {0} >> {1}".format(before, after), 'yellow')))
```

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: on_server_role_update() missing 1 positional argument: 'after'
```

You see? I have the argument but it shows an error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`on_server_role_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_server_role_update) should have exactly two arguments: a `Role` `before` and a `Role` `after`.  Why did you think there was a third `role` argument?

```
@bot.event
async def on_server_role_update(before, after):
    server_blue = colored(str(before.server), 'blue')
    msg = "Role Updated: {0} >> {1}".format(before, after)
    color_msg = colored(msg, 'yellow')
    print("[{}] {}".format(server_blue, color_msg))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more thing, can I somehow add the "message" argument? to have the "message.timestamp"

Comment: No.  There's no messages involved here.  You can use `time.time()` to resolve the timestamp when you receive the event.

Comment: i got it, thank you so much xD you've helpd me a lot